# Restrict access to page with PHP

Tags: php, session

This seems really simple, and I see a lot of documentation about it, but I can't get it to work. Basically, I have a page "download-software.php" that we want only to be accessed from "download-registration.php" On the second page "download-registration.php" I have this:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['authenticated'] = 'yes';
?>
```

and on the first page "download-software.php" I have this:

```
<?php
 session_start();
  if($_SESSION['authenticated'] != 'yes') {
    header("Location: http://kinetick.com/V3/download-free.php");
   };
 ?>
```

I need to kick the browser to the "download-free.php" page if they dont come from the first page. Can anyone help me out pls?

**Edit****
added session_start(); still doesn't work.

Comment: You need another `session_start()` in the second file.

Comment: @Pekka - I added it, still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `session_start()` on download-software.php
You must always call `session_start()` before any html data to be able to use $_SESSION in your script

Comment: On download-software.php, what print var_dump($_SESSION) ?

Comment: on download-software.php I added "echo $_SESSION['authenticated'];" I think that's the same as var_dump($_SESSION) and it displays "yes" its getting the value "yes" regardless of where the page comes from

Comment: with var_dump... it prints "array(1) { ["authenticated"]=>  string(3) "yes" "

Comment: Is != 'yes' giving it the value 'yes'?

Comment: Maybe weird boolean issue, try if($_SESSION['authenticated'] !== 'yes')

Comment: @Dirty you *are* restarting the browser in between attempts to delete the previous session, right?

Comment: @Pekka - yes, I was but it got me to look close at the code, I had a ":" instead of a ";" at the end of the header line. Thanks all!

Comment: @Pekka & @MatTheCat - could you add this to the form processing script somehow? right now if you go to the first page, then enter the url for the second it will go to it. I would prefer it only redirects to that page on form submission

Answer (score 2):

You need to add another `session_start()` to the beginning of download-software.php to resume the session you started from download-registration.php.